# Moving the Views header

Tags: views

I've enabled the Result summary in the Header for my view... However, it is being displayed at the top of the conetnt. I would like it to be display in between the search form and the search results. Is the only way to do this via a template?

The view is made up of nodes being imported using a Feeds module.

They are displayed in a table, and there is a search on top...

Comment: Please give more details as in what you are trying to achieve, what the view is about, etc.

Comment: Edited my post. Hope this is enough detail...

Comment: Your search is a filter right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using a template file will be the easiest way to do this.

In your view `=>` click `Theming information`

> => Select the tpl file that suits you best
>
> => place that tpl file in your templates folder under your theme
>
> => for the content of the file
>
> => under Theming Information in your view click `Display output`
>
> => copy that content to your tpl and change the position of your header
>
> => come back to Theming Information and click `Rescan template files` - your newly added tpl(under your theme directory) should be highlighted(bold) now, which means you tpl is up and working!

Hope this helps.

[I am sure you might know how to do all this, yet putting it in details might help somebody else looking for the same solution who hasn't yet learned how to :)]